# Plasma: how were the UTXO bitmaps conceptualised and how will they be stored?

Tags: storage, data-types, plasma, storage-trie

From the [white paper](https://plasma.io/plasma.pdf), page 5:

> We construct an interactive game whereby the exiting party attests to
>   a bitmap of participants’ ledger outputs arranged in an UTXO model
>   which requests a withdrawal.

Are these bitmaps matrixes of bits, just like in images? Or key-value pairs? Then, given the underlying economic incentives of Plasma, who stores them and how? Is there a model similar to Bitcon's UTXO storage, i.e. `$DATADIR/chainstate`?